# How can I mock a function called inside function in Jest with ES6?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, es6-modules

When I'm using CommonJS Following test have no problem.

file sub.js:

```
function sub () {

    console.log ( "sub" );
    return ( 20 );

}

module.exports = sub;
```

file main.js :

```
const sub = require ( "./sub.js" );

function main () {

    console.log ( "main" );
    return sub ();

}

module.exports = main;
```

file index.js :

```
let main = require("./main.js");

function entryPoint () {

    return main ();

}

module.exports = entryPoint;
```

file index.spec.js :

```
jest.mock ( "./sub" );
let sub = require ( "./sub" );

sub.mockImplementation ( () => {

    return ( 10 );

} );

let entryPoint = require('./index.js');

describe ( "jest-test", () => {

    it ( "should run mocked sub", () => {

        expect ( entryPoint ()  ).toBe ( 10 );

    } );

} );
```

file packages.json :

```
{
  "name": "jest-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose --maxWorkers=1 --detectOpenHandles",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^27.4.7"
  }
}
```

with above source code, test success because function sub is changed with mocked function.

so original sub is not called, instead mocked sub is called so entryPoint returns 10
instead of 20

Now, I changed source code to ES6 module

file sub.js :

```
function sub () {

    console.log ( "sub" );
    return ( 20 );

}

export default sub;
```

file main.js :

```
import sub from "./sub.js";

function main () {

    console.log ( "main" );
    return sub ();

}

export default main;
```

file index.js :

```
import main from "./main.js";

function entryPoint () {

    return main ();

}

export default entryPoint;
```

file index.spec.js :

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

jest.mock ( "./sub" );
import sub from "./sub";

sub.mockImplementation ( () => {

    return ( 10 );

} );

import entryPoint from "./index.js";

describe ( "jest-test", () => {

    it ( "should run mocked sub", () => {

        expect ( entryPoint ()  ).toBe ( 10 );

    } );

} );
```

file package.json :

```
{
  "name": "jest-test",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --verbose --maxWorkers=1 --detectOpenHandles"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^27.4.7"
  }
}
```

It's almost same code except I replaced require to import.
But I got error 'mockImplementation is not a function'

I've tried following index.spec.js but neither worked for me

another index.spec.js :

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

jest.mock ( "./sub", () => {

  return 10;

} );

import sub from "./sub";


import entryPoint from "./index.js";

describe ( "jest-test", () => {

    it ( "should run mocked sub", () => {

        expect ( entryPoint ()  ).toBe ( 10 );

    } );

} );
```

error was gone but mocked function is not called
so entryPoint return 20 and test failed

What can I do mock a function inside function with ES6 module?

I searched google but I couldn't get a answer.

please help me!!

Comment: Remember that jest's ES module support [is still experimental](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) - are you remembering to run with Node's `--experimental-vm-modules` flag?